# How to pass huge 2D numpy array to c function

Tags: python, arrays, c, numpy, ctypes

Good day,

I am new to C and ctypes in Python.

I am trying to pass a C function into the Python code.

I keep receiving the following error: "access violation reading 0x0..." when reading a 2D arrays ("St" of shape 10,000 x 521 and "dZ" of shape 10,000 x 520) in the following C function:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double change (double * dZ, double * St, size_t lenTaus, size_t lenSims)
{
    size_t i, j;
    double a, b;
    for (i = 0; i < lenSims; i++) /*Iterate through simulations.*/
    {
        for (j = 0; j < (lenTaus - 1); j++) /*Iterate through taus.*/
        {
            a = St[lenTaus * i + j];
            b = dZ[lenTaus * i + j];
        }
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

The variables "lenSims" and "lenTaus" are 10,000 and 521 respectively.

The Python code to call the C function is:

```
import ctypes
impor t numpy as np
cCode = ctypes.CDLL("cCode_e.so") ### Read the C code in a form of shared library.
cCode.change.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_size_t] ### Let know what kind of input we provide to the C function.
cCode.change.restype = ctypes.c_double ### Let know what kind of output we expect from the C function.
St_Python = np.zeros([10000,521])
dZ_Python = np.random.randn(10000,520)
St = St_Python.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)) ### Convert a numpy array into a pointer to an array of doubles.
dZ = dZ_Python.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)) ### Convert a numpy array into a pointer to an array of doubles.
lenTaus = St_Python.shape[1] ### Find the number of columns in the original array.
lenSims = St_Python.shape[0] ### Find the number of rows in the original array.
out = cCode.change(dZ, St, lenTaus, lenSims) ### Call the C function
```

If I understand the problem correctly, I work with memory incorrectly when passing the whole arrays as pointers to the C function. But I do not know how to pass them in the correct way.

May I ask for your help?

Best regards,

Evgenii

Comment: how do you create `St_Python` and `dZ_Python` arrays? Maybe there is not enough data in one of them?

Comment: The way arrays are processed seems wrong. If one is *10000X521* (10000 rows and 521 columns), the 1st index that should be traversed is 10000 (*lenTaus*). Also 520 corresponds to *lenSims - 1*. Switch  `lenSims` with `(lenTaus - 1)` in the 2 loops. and indexing should be `[lenSims * i + j]`.

Comment: Hello, I added the definition of the "St_Python" and "dZ_Python" arrays in Python.

Comment: does `dZ_Python = np.random.randn(10000,520)` -> `dZ_Python = np.random.randn(10000,521)` fix the problem?

Comment: Also why did you hardcode the values in *Python* when creating the arrays, instead using `St_Python.shape[]`? Maybe they differ.

Comment: @tstanisl I am implementing the Geometric Brownian Motion. The first column gives basis for the second one, the second for the third and so on. Therefore, I need 521 columns for the "St_Python" array (1 as basis and 520 to be re-written). The 520 columns of the "dZ_Python" array enter the formula later for 520 re-writes to be completed. The number of dimensions is correct to my knowledge as it works in Python FOR loops.

Comment: @CristiFati If I understand it correctly then the C version of the numpy array is just a vector representation of the 2D array (one line of values I mean). If this is true then I need to re-write each rows column by column with the jump by ("lenTaus" * "i" + "j") values in the vector of values. Is my understanding of the conversion wrong?

Comment: @EvgeniiDanilov: you are correct, memory is a 1D array of bytes, and every array no matter how many dimensions, will be represented as 1D (well, there are some memory alignment considerations, but let's leave them aside for now). But I think, you're confusing row and column numbers. Row number is (generally) the 1st. Also traversing a 2D array by column is extremely inefficient.

Comment: @CristiFati: Thank you for noticing it. I shall try re-writing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that the problem is caused by a buffer overflow.

Assuming that the arrays are defined as:

```
St_Python = np.zeros([10000,521])
dZ_Python = np.random.randn(10000,520)
```

In C function the parameters `lenTaus` and `LenSims` are `521` and `10000` respectively.
As result the final offset at which `dZ` is accessed is:

```c
lenTaus * i + j = lenTaus * (lenSims-1) + (lenTaus - 1 - 1)
                = 521*9999 + 521-1-1
                = 5209998
```

The size of `dz` is `10000 * 520` what is `5200000` that is smaller than the final offset thus there is a buffer overflow and *Undefined Behavior* is invoked.

One of solutions is to change offset calculations for `dZ` to:

```
            b = dZ[(lenTaus - 1) * i + j];
```